# Jetpack compose navigation error: IllegalStateException: no event down from INITIALIZED in component NavBackStackEntry

Tags: android, navigation, admob, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using admob AppOpenAd in my app, and in their requirements I need to show their ad only on top of a screen with no banner ads. therefore, before I display the app-open-ad I navigate the user to a splash screen, showing the ad, and when the user closes the ad, I redirect him back to the desired screen.

I've used admob documentation in here to recognize life cycle events, and check if the user resumed the app:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open?hl=en#lifecycleobserver

so when I need to show the ad I do it osmething like this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread { _navController?.navigate(adSplashRoute) }
isShowingAd = true
appOpenAd?.show(activity)
```

and when the user done with the add I redirect him back:

```
    override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
        // Called when full screen content is dismissed.
        // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
        Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.")
        appOpenAd = null
        isShowingAd = false
        activity.runOnUiThread { _navController?.popBackStack() }

        onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete()
        loadAd(activity)
    }
```

I use a dedicated new `AppOpenAdManager` class which I create in te `MainActivity` class and inject it using `hilt`:

```
@Inject
lateinit var appOpenManager: AppOpenAdManager
```

and pass it to my composable in the `onCreate` method inside `MainActivity`:

```
setContent {
    val darkTheme = shouldUseDarkTheme(uiState)

    MainAppTheme(darkTheme = darkTheme) {
        MainAppComposable(appOpenManager = appOpenManager)
    }
}
```

in my `MainAppComposable` I have an "appState" object like in google example app `NowInAndroid` where I create a `navController` object, and then I pass it to the `AppOpenAdManager` class:

```
val appState = rememberMainAppState(
    activity = LocalContext.current.findActivity(),
    appOpenManager = appOpenManager,
)
appOpenManager.setNavController(appState.navController)
```

I think this wraps up my main implementation, and the thing is that it works, and it works fine for 95% of the users.
for some reason, which I canot understand why, I see in my crashlytics report on production, that sometimes the app crashes with this error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no event down from INITIALIZED in component NavBackStackEntry(424f7fd8-c853-473e-a959-d5a14f1e3b48) destination=Destination(0x71c279e0) route=splash_route
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.kt:126)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.kt:106)
       at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.updateState(NavBackStackEntry.kt:193)
       at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.setMaxLifecycle(NavBackStackEntry.kt:166)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.updateBackStackLifecycle$navigation_runtime_release(NavController.kt:1087)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.dispatchOnDestinationChanged(NavController.kt:991)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1843)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1785)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:2186)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:2181)
```

I tried to reproduce it, but for me everything works and the error doesn't occuer.
I've red in some other answers here that it happnes when the screen skips life cycle events like DESTROY for example, but I cannot understand why and how can I fix it.

any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing the same crash logs although it's not the AdMob ad but the User Messaging Platform message dialog.